# Ubuntu MATE window list app icon rows

Tags: ubuntu-mate

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04, the Window List app at the bottom of my screen displays two rows for the window buttons. This is hard on my eyes. I'd like to have just one row, like it was before I upgraded. See the current state of my Window List app in this screen shot: [Window List App.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrtfr.png)

The solution that is often given is to expand the size of the panel. All that does is make the bottom panel obnoxiously large and increase the number of rows: [bigger panel, more rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m177n.png). I want just one row with nice readable icons.

I am using Ubuntu MATE 1.18.0.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: smaller panel, or larger font will make it drop to single row